# problem with union and intersection type in react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
type LinkProps =  {
    children: any:
    ....(some more common props)

};
type LinkWithToProps = LinkProps & {
    to: string | { pathname: string };
};
type LinkWithOnclickProps = LinkProps & {
    onClick: (params: any) => void;
};
type propsType = LinkWithOnclickProps | LinkWithToProps
const InternalLink = (props: propsType) => {
    const {to, onClick, children} = props;
}
```

I am trying to use the union and intersection concept here for props in react component. what I want to do is either my component can have a "to" prop or a "onClick" prop but if both of them are not present then typescript should complain.

As far as my understanding is i am combining my `linkProps` with both the `LinkWithToProps` and `LinkWithOnclickProps` and then using the `|` so only 1 of them get used at a time.

but typescript is complaining that `Property 'to' does not exist on type 'propsType'.` and same for `onlCick` as well. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how TS unions work.

I believe there is only one type safe solution. You should add required property to both types.
Here you have an example:

```js
import React from 'react';

type LinkProps = {
    children: any;

};
type LinkWithToProps = LinkProps & {
    to: string | { pathname: string };
} & { type: 'with' }

type LinkWithOnclickProps = LinkProps & {
    onClick: (params: any) => void;
} & { type: 'without' };

type Props = LinkWithOnclickProps | LinkWithToProps

const InternalLink: React.VFC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    if (props.type === 'with') {
        const p = props; // LinkWithToProps
    }

    if (props.type === 'without') {
        const p = props; // LinkWithOnclickProps
    }
    return null
}
```

You can also use typeguards.

[Here](https://catchts.com/unions) you can find more examples

In your case: `const {to, onClick, children} = props;` TS is unable to figure out which property exists and which not.
In this particular case, TS is only 100% sure about `children` property.

You should help TS with condition

Comment: This would still require one to write <Link ... type="with"> it seems?

Comment: @philk yes, property `type` make this union discriminated. However you can overload your react component and make union more useful. See [this example](https://tsplay.dev/N7ygnW)